# changing part of text size with java for android

Tags: android

*As I add text to my text view with java, I want some text to be smaller and some to be   bigger. Is there a way I can change the text size as I add it with java?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use [Spannable String](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) for this purpose and for Tutorial you can see it [here](http://nocturnaldev.com/2013/05/28/using-spannable-strings-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Each text view has a value for the size of the text contained in that view.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you could add several text views in a row with different text sizes to simulate what it sounds like you want.

Use a relative view, add a text view to it and align it however you want with wrap_content for width and then just add the other text views using an alignment toRightOf previous textview.

Comment: This is not a feasible apporach if you want to vari sizes in a paragraph or multiple fields you need to have track of all the Fields that you want to handle and make it more hactic for developer

Comment: I agree Usman, I believe the Spannable option you suggested makes more sense.  Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use webview and html to make a richtextbox like view. Text widget don't have this feature. Maybe there would be 3rd party widget for this also.

Answer (score -1):

Create 2 separate TextView's, place them next to each other and set different text size on each:

```
TextView myTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view_1);
TextView myTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view_2);

float textSize1 = 20.0;
myTextView1.setTextSize(textSize1);

float textSize2 = 30.0
myTextView2.setTextSize(textSize2);
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text_view_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test 1"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text_view_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test 2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```